# Can I set the decimal symbol to use everywhere in my application

Tags: c#, windows, formatting, number-formatting, regional-settings

I tracked down a bug in my application that occurred for people in countries where the default decimal symbol was a comma instead of a period. Is there any way in C# to set the decimal symbol for my application without affecting other apps or permanently changing the system settings? 
I tried this but it says the NumberDecimalSeparator is readonly.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
```

Comment: Wouldn't your users in those countries *want* to see decimal numbers in the format they're familiar with? You should only enforce "." when it's *not* for user consumption - and your code should be aware of when it's formatting/parsing for machines, and when it's doing it for users.

Comment: I thnk you're going about the fix in the wrong direction. Surely you should be changing your application to respect how your users see formats as correct?

Comment: Yes ideally I would just be able to use the users settings but I am using NCalc to evaluate equations and commas are necessary for separating parameters so I don't think I could use them for decimals too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I you still need to do that you can change the CurrentCulture on the thread like so:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-Us");
```

Chooe a Culture that has the decimal properties you need.

```
var numpre = 1.1.ToString();
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-Us");
var numpost = 1.1.ToString();
numpre.Dump();
numpost.Dump();
```

Output:

> 1,1
>   1.1

Comment: Ah of course. I tried setting the NumberFormat and the NumberDecimalSeparator but didn't try setting the CurrentCulture. Unfortunately my app is multi threaded so I need to figure out how to set this on every thread.

Comment: You say you use NCalc. Can't you have a proxy around the NCalc classes where you set the Culture just before the call to NCalc methods (and reset after the call is done)?

Comment: The issue happens wherever I auto generate the text for an equation that has a decimal number in it. I could search for everywhere I am doing that and temporarily set the culture info but I would be easier to just set it once globally. It looks like if I set the culture info in a parent thread then all child threads will inherit it's settings so this shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the situation, the right thing to do may not be to try to enforce a format, but to make your application aware of the locale and take it into account. Which is something really easy to do since .NET has it all implemented already (otherwise it would be a nightmare).

I'd say there are two cases to treat: when data can be passed from one machine to another (some stored data, a file, a script, etc.), and when it is not supposed to (a visual feedback, a value field, etc.).

**When it's about data that can be passed from one machine to another**, you have to choose a format that is culture agnostic. This will guarantee the machines use the same format and interpret a given data the same way regardless of the machine user settings. That's what programming languages do, and seems to be your case.

The .NET library provides `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` for this:

```
double x = 0.0;
double.TryParse(source, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out x);
string str = x.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**When it's about local information**, you should read and write in the language of the user, using his locale to parse numbers in inputs (text fields) and format them in outputs. This tends to be neglected, but I think it is a very important point, as a number like 1,234.567 will have a radically different meaning depending on the culture. See for example how a software like Microsoft Excel will represent and let you enter numbers differently depending on your environment settings.

In this case the above code snippet would become:

```
double x = 0.0;
double.TryParse(source, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, out x);
string str = x.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
```

---

See more on the MSDN documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but in my case I don't think this will work. I need to be able to evaluate an equation that is stored in an editable text field so if at any point I convert "Pow(2.1,3)" to "Pow(2,1,3)" I am going to loose some necessary info.

Comment: Oh I see, this would fall under the data storage case, and my UI/storage definition is broken here.

Comment: ah right. I could do that but I'd rather not have to find everywhere I am converting a double to a string. But if I have any issues with rene's solution I may try this out. I guess this is a cleaner solution though as it wouldn't affect anything I wasn't intending to change.

Comment: Not so long ago I saw some code with this kind of bug, and although it felt a bit daunting, going through all string/float conversions and asking oneself if it was sound, was the right thing to do. Anyway, I edited my answer.